# React-Navigation tabNavigator with 7 tabs - extending it beyond screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Using react-navigation I've created a tabNavigator with multiple tabs(7 in total). I want to have the tabs extend beyond the screen so that a user swipes across the top to see the remaining items. However, when I create the tabNavigator the tabs only fit in the screen width and the title text overlaps each other.

I've checked the docs and the open issues on the project's github, I've Googled for a solution, and I can't find anything on Stackoverflow addressing this issue. Here is an example code:

```
const TabsScreen = TabNavigator({
  tab1: { screen: Tab1Screen },
  tab2: { screen: Tab2Screen },
  tab3: { screen: Tab3Screen },
  tab4: { screen: Tab4Screen },
  tab5: { screen: Tab5Screen },
  tab6: { screen: Tab6Screen },
  tab7: { screen: Tab7Screen }
}, {
  swipeEnabled: true,
  tabBarPosition: 'top',
  navigationOptions: {
    lazy: true //I am using "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.22"
  },
  tabBarOptions: {
    scrollEnabled: true,
    labelStyle: {
      width: 200, // I tried setting this based on screensize, etc
      fontSize: 18
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: You'll need to implement a custom [`tabBarComponent`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#TabNavigatorConfig). You can take a look at the `TabBarBottom` and `TabBarTop` implementations in the [source code](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/tree/master/src/views/TabView) to see what things you might need to do. Beyond that advice, this is probably a bit too broad of a question to try and answer.

Comment: Hey that worked! If you add that as an answer I can mark it as the best answer. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to implement a custom [`tabBarComponent`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#TabNavigatorConfig). You can take a look at the `TabBarBottom` and `TabBarTop` implementations in the [source code](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/tree/master/src/views/TabView) to see what things you might need to do. Beyond that advice, this is probably a bit too broad of a question to try and answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try alternative solution:
1.Specify tab width inside tabBarOptions

`tabStyle: {
        width: Dimensions.get("window").width / 3.5
      }`

2. Set scroll enable inside tabBarOptions
   `scrollEnabled: true`

so to sum up,tabbaroptions will look like

` tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: Colors.FontColors.base_grey,
      inactiveTintColor: Colors.FontColors.light_grey,

```
  tabStyle: {
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width / 3.5 // number of tabs are 4
  },
  scrollEnabled: true
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

As other people have mentioned, you will need to implement a custom component, I have been recently been working with BottomTabNavigator, invoked through app.js. Navigation
import Navigation from './navigation';

Navigation leads to BottomTabNavigator, but heres the rub, last time I checked I found that when using this particular Navigator, it only allows about 4 or 5 tabs before it gives a completely uncalled for and unnecessary stack error, it simply refused to acknowledge the rest of the navigator!